# How to verify if all the T-SQL queries inside an abc.sql file are executed successfully through shell script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
UPDATE dbo.microkernel_component_instance SET health_status = 'MAINTENANCE';
UPDATE dbo.tenant_app_component_instance SET health_status = 'MAINTENANCE';
UPDATE dbo.tenant_instance SET health_status = 'MAINTENANCE';
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
while read line; do
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd  -S abc -d testdb -U amdin -P admin -e "$line"
done < abc.sql
```

ERROR:

> Sqlcmd: 'UPDATE dbo.microkernel_component_instance SET health_status = 'MAINTENANCE';': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

Please let me know how I could resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spool the shell script to a log file (so the results are written in to it)...later on you can review the log file if a SQL statement failed for some reason

Answer (score 0):

`sqlcmd -i inputfile` and check retval